# main content intruding on my header

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning by doing with css/html can anyone explain to me why the main content of the page(which I am yet to style) is intruding upon my header? code is below:

```
    body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {

    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}


/*-----------Start Header-----------*/
header{

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    height: 200px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;


}

header>img{

    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
}
header>h1{

    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    float: right;
}


/*----------Start Nav-----------*/

#horznav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;

}
#horznav>a{

    width: 20%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 1.75vw;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;

}



#horznav>a:hover{

    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*------------End Nav----------------------*/

/*----------- End Header --------------------*/
```

And here is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Project 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>



    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <header>

                    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yik/e79/yike79brT.png" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.">

                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>

                    <nav id="horznav">

                        <a class= 'navitems nav1' href="">Home</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav2' href="">About</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav3' href="">Contact</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav4' href="">Affiliates</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav5' href="">Coming Soon</a>

                    </nav>

            </header>

            <main id="content">

                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>
                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>
                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>

            </main> 

            <footer>

                <section id="left">

                    <p id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
                    <p id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur modi, quia consequuntur.</p>

                </section>

                <section id="right">

                    <img src="http://iconion.com/posts/images/social-icons.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor." id="socialmedia">

                </section>

            </footer>

        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

I hope this is an easy fix, please explain the reason for this happening.

Thank You All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are applying `height` which means if the contents inside have larger height than it will overflow. Please use `min-height` so it can expand if it needs to be.

P.S. You need to write more respectable code. It's very bad practice to use % everywhere.

```css
 body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {

    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}


/*-----------Start Header-----------*/
header{

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;


}

header>img{

    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
}
header>h1{

    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    float: right;
}


/*----------Start Nav-----------*/

#horznav {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;

}
#horznav>a{

    width: 20%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 1.75vw;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;

}



#horznav>a:hover{

    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*------------End Nav----------------------*/

/*----------- End Header --------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">

            <header>

                    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yik/e79/yike79brT.png" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.">

                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>

                    <nav id="horznav">

                        <a class= 'navitems nav1' href="">Home</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav2' href="">About</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav3' href="">Contact</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav4' href="">Affiliates</a>
                        <a class= 'navitems nav5' href="">Coming Soon</a>

                    </nav>

            </header>

            <main id="content">

                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>
                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>
                <section class="part">
                    <article id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro at vero esse error eius laborum illum magni qui natus quisquam culpa, quaerat, ullam impedit. Nobis, repellendus itaque commodi! Iure, distinctio.</article>
                    <article id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil aut quis mollitia, voluptates alias odit amet ullam praesentium molestias sapiente ex est. Repudiandae expedita cupiditate illo quis veritatis nemo, voluptates architecto incidunt ratione in, voluptate neque amet quaerat eligendi ipsum earum aliquid dolorum inventore non natus. Autem dignissimos similique at possimus voluptatum, hic vel sunt velit. Rerum blanditiis voluptate animi molestias, hic ab natus vitae, cum labore facere harum, placeat ea illum officia magni quis. Earum atque illum sit voluptate, veritatis asperiores, facere velit ipsam laborum hic iusto blanditiis possimus, molestias maxime sed! Excepturi nemo, rem quisquam quae, dolore magni.</article>
                </section>

            </main> 

            <footer>

                <section id="left">

                    <p id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
                    <p id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur modi, quia consequuntur.</p>

                </section>

                <section id="right">

                    <img src="http://iconion.com/posts/images/social-icons.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor." id="socialmedia">

                </section>

            </footer>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please elaborate on your comment "P.S. You need to write more respectable code. It's very bad practice to use % everywhere." the reason i am using percent so much is to keep it responsive

Comment: You can use media query for responsiveness. At some point, it makes sense to use % unit, but to achieve responsiveness you must use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding overflow:hidden to header. Because you are floating the elements inside header, the header is collapsing. Add border to header to see what I mean. If you use float to an element you need to overflow:hidden its parent to prevent this from happening.

Hope it helps

Comment: This just cuts the bottom of my header off and does not solve the issue thank you anyway

Comment: so try removing the height:200px and change it to min-height:200px or height:auto

Comment: Great. glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can replace height in header:

Replease this:

```
header {
  height: 200px;
}
```

With this css:

```
header {
  height: auto;
}
```

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bd9mgexg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `float` in your header elements is causing it to collapse with your content.

Since float usually creates unexpected results, I recommend you to use a `flexbox`, a new layout that is starting to work on most browsers. This is a summary of what it does extracted from MDN:

> The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox, is a layout mode providing for the arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins collapse with the margins of its contents.

If you are interested in using it
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is the full tutorial from MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You have added

```
header>h1{

    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    float: right;
}
```

and the

```
header{

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    height: 200px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;


}
```

so header height is 200 px and you have kept the height of h1 as 70% of that so change the header>h1 selector as per your liking and it will work

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Comment: The height of h1 should be 70% of the header should it not?

Comment: if you keep the header @ 70% then its height will be 140px , do u want such a big h1?

Comment: No i have made these changes it is now much smaller 40 px